# Open Source Workflow Engines for MVC projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workflow

I am trying to explore Open Source Workflow Engines for MVC 5.0 application. I need to understand from you folks the pros and cons of some of the open source tools used by you all.

I have around 200 workflows (Mostly Approval sort of wf with AD integration) need to be implemented and I need to reduce the development

Comment: Few of my previous question were never answered. Hope i get to see some answers this time

Comment: Not likely, since this one will be closed soon as either too broad, primarily opinionated, or asking for recommendations on tools or libraries. Either of the three would be a valid reason to close. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.